# Migrated from MVC3 to MVC4  and Azure 1.7 - Why does iisexpress.exe now appear in log files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, azure-storage

I have a ASP MVC4 Windows Azure application. The application is working but since moving to MVC4 and the latest version of the Azure library I noticed start-up time is very slow. I checked and notice the following in the log files:

Before Migration:

```
'WaIISHost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WaIISHost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WaIISHost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WaIISHost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WaIISHost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Auto-attach to process '[8120] w3wp.exe' on machine 'X301' succeeded.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

After Migration:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 101 : Role environment . INITIALIZED
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'
'WaIISHost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Code K\ 2\\csx\Debug\roles\WebUx\approot\bin\WebUx.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WaIISHost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'
'WaIISHost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Code K\ 2\\csx\Debug\roles\WebUx\approot\bin\EntityFramework.dll'
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 200 : 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'
```

The key thing here is that after I migrated then I NOW see many rows in the output log that refer to iisexpress.exe

Can someone give me some advice on this. Is there a reason why it changed to iisexpress and why is the start up time 4-5 times slower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with SDK 1.7 (June 2012) the Windows Azure compute emulator uses IIS Express as the default web server.  If you need/want to use Full IIS instead, you can switch that - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156006.aspx

Answer (score 1):

IISExpress is lightweight standalone webserver which is default web server for Windows Azure SDK from 1.7. and the idea behind this changes is that users will have much more flexibility to play with web server with small footprint and load on demand.

This [forum](http://forums.iis.net/t/1175052.aspx) has good discussion around why there is some (4-5 time) performance issues with IISExpress comparative to Full IIS. ScottGu explains the advantage of using IISExpress [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx) so you sure can take a look.

Based on your understanding you can choose IISExpress or Full IIS as your web server for Windows Azure application as suggested by @mcollier. Finally if you choose to use IISExpress, you can make it perform better if you run as service which will do much better job.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can run this as a service. Does this mean it would be running all the time rather than having to start up each time I build in VS2010?